# The proof for the complexity of sorting algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting, asymptotic-complexity

The theorem denotes that:

Any comparison sorting algorithm performs Ω(nlg(n)) comparisons in the worst case.

To prove that I found:

Looking the worst case number of comparisons that an algorithm performs, means the longest path from the root to a leaf in its decision-tree.

As a binary tree of height h has at most 2^h leafs, and there are n! permutations (output), we have:

> 2^h ≥ n!

I understand that we can rewrite `2^h ≥ n!` as `h ≥ log2(n!)` but how can we end up with:

> h ≥ log2(n!) = Ω(n*lg(n)) ?

Answer (score 4):

Applying [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) to the log<sub>2</sub>(n!) term gives:

n log<sub>2</sub>(n) - log<sub>2</sub>(e)*n + O(log<sub>2</sub>(n))

which is Ω(n log<sub>2</sub>(n))

Answer (score 0):

n! is the product of n numbers that are less than or equal to n, so:

```
log(n!) < log(n^n)
=> log(n!) < n*log(n)
```

and n! is the product of n/2 numbers that are at least n/2, as well as some other numbers > 1, so:

```
log(n!) > log((n/2)^(n/2))  
=> log(n!) > n*log(n/2)/2
=> log(n!) > n*(log(n)-log(2))/2
=> log(n!) > n*log(n)/4 when log(n) - log(2) > log(n)/2
=> log(n!) > n*log(n)/4 when log(n) > 2log(2)
=> log(n!) > n*log(n)/4 when n > 4
```